# Check if category has parent

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm in mid of creating my own cms . And now i want to show which one of the category has parent but i don't know how, so please help me.

my category table

```
 idkategori  |  namakategori  | parentid 
      1         Programming         0
      2            PHP              1
```

Or i need relationship table for my categories?

My Controller so far.

```
function tampilmenu()
{
            $sql              = "select * from fc_kategori";
            $data['kategori'] = $this->bymodel->tampildata($sql);
            $sql1             = "select parentid from fc_kategori";
            $data['parent']   = $this->bymodel->tampildata($sql1);
                            $id=array();
                foreach ($data['parent'] as $paren)
            {
                $id[]=$paren->parentid;
            }
            foreach ($data['kategori'] as $cat) 
            if(in_array($cat->parentid,$id))
            {
                        $have ='Yes';
            }
            else
            {
                        $have ='No';
            }
            echo $cat->idkategori.$have;
                                    }   

}
```

my model

```
function tampildata ($sql)
{
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Please don't laugh on me.

Comment: what do you mean by `which one of the category has parent`? Explain briefly.

Comment: You db structure looks ok...if `parentid=0` then category is a parent, if `parentid>0` then the `parentid` is the id of the parent category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kindly follow:**

1) Since you are using a **`MVC framework`**, never write queries inside the controller (queries should always be written in models).
2) Never use raw queries, since CI provides you what is called as **`Active Record`**.
3) Also never pass **`direct queries`** anywhere you'll possibly code in whichever language. Always pass data and make do that function to compute and query process.
4) Remember, in CI **`Models`** are only used for database functionalities, **`Views`** are only used for your HTML markups and **`Controllers`** acts as the mediator between models and views.

**Your code:**

**Controller -**

```
public function tampilmenu()
{
    $categories = $this->bymodel->get_category_having_parent();

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($categories);

    // this will return object having all categories that are parents
}
```

**Model -**

```
public function get_category_having_parent()
{
    $parent_ids = array();
    $ps = $this->get("parentid");
    foreach($ps as $p)
    {
       $parent_ids[] = $p->parentid;
    } 

    $this->db->where_in("id", $parent_ids);
    $query = $this->db->get("fc_kategori");
    return $query->result();
}

public function get($column="*")
{
    $this->db->select($column);
    $query = $this->db->get("fc_kategori");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works man. Sory for my bad english. so i can't use my controller ? because i learn it from someone.by the way echo $cat->idkategori.$have; just for tes